# Elasticsearch query - print certain field based on other field

Tags: python, elasticsearch, kibana, elasticsearch-query

My goal is to find max value in one field and print another field in this found document.
My query so far:

```
{
        "fields": ["text"], //NOT WORKING
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "_type:bmw AND _exists_:car_type",
      "analyze_wildcard": True
    }
  },
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "2": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "compound",
        "size": 5,
        "order": {
          "2-orderAgg": "desc"
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "2-orderAgg": {
          "max": {
            "field": "compound"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Result is

```
'buckets': [{'doc_count': 1, '2-orderAgg': {'value': 0.8442}, 'key': 0.8442}, {'doc_count': 1, '2-orderAgg': {'value': 0.7777}, 'key': 0.7777}, {'doc_count': 1, '2-orderAgg': {'value': 0.7579}, 'key': 0.7579}, {'doc_count': 1, '2-orderAgg': {'value': 0.6476}, 'key': 0.6476}, {'doc_count': 1, '2-orderAgg': {'value': 0.6369}, 'key': 0.6369}]
```

Now I need to print `text` field in document contains `compound` value 0.8442 and so on.. Thank you for your advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I achieved this with a small workaroud. It's not pretty but at final I get what I wanted. 
Firstly I used response from first query. Than I grabbed all `keys` from those dictionary and perform new query to find certain document's `id`.

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "analyze_wildcard": True,
      "query": "_type:bmw AND compound:"+str(0.8442)+" AND _exists_:car_type"
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "3": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "id_str",
        "size": 20,
        "order": {
          "_count": "desc"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

than iterate through response and search document by this `id` field

```
for y in res1:
    res3 = es.search(index='indexname', body={
                      "size" : 1,
                      "query": {
                        "bool": {
                          "must": [
                            {
                              "match": {
                                "id_str": y['key']
                              }
                            }
                          ]
                        }
                      }
                    })
                    for x in res3['hits']['hits']:
                        print (x['_source']['text'])
```

now result is

```
Diamond stitch leather is a great addition to any custom vehicle. Prices start from 2k! @bmw i8 getting under car...
```

which is text what I wanted.